# Photoshop sc6 on Ubuntu 14.04 x86

Tags: bittorrent, photoshop

I want a link to download and install Photoshop CS6 in Ubuntu 14.04 x86 without problems, if possible on torrent.

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's blatantly asking how to pirate a piece software and install it.

Comment: I prefer Gimp in fact, because a lot of pirated Photoshop "Limited Functionality". But I need the possibility of the amendment to the PSD files are larger than the Gimp validity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of July 20, 2016 Codeweavers Crossover is the best software for installing Abode Photoshop CS6 in Linux, but it's still not good enough for use at work. Crossover still says Photoshop CS6 has only "Limited Functionality". You deserve to get more than limited functionality for the price of a license for Abode Photoshop CS6. If your Photoshop is pirated, you'll be lucky to get even that limited functionality.

What does "Limited Functionality" mean? It means that halfway through your Photoshop project, you have to delete everything and start over in GIMP because an important Photoshop feature that you need doesn't work in Linux. I have licensed copies of both Crossover and Photoshop, but I always use GIMP instead, because everything works and GIMP is always kept up-to-date. I could run Photoshop in Windows, but what's the point when my up-to-date version of GIMP has more features than my obsolete version of Photoshop which I haven't used in years.

Comment: I was thinking of training to upgrade pocket version 2.9.4 today to forget Photoshop final
Thank you so much ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop is only available for the Windows and MacOS platforms. But on Linux you can install the Windows version through `wine`. So to use photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu, first install `wine`:

**Step 1. Install the Wine Team Ubuntu PPA**

open the Terminal and :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa     
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

**Step 2. Using winetricks to get install dependencies for Photoshop CS6**

Now that we have the most recent build of wine, we can get started on fetching the necessary build packages to run the **Photoshop** installer.

Here’s the command to issue and pull those **dependencies**

> winetricks atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1
>   vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko

If a few errors pop-up, don’t worry – chances are this install will still work.

**Step 3. Running the Photoshop CS6 installer**

Now that you have all dependencies required to run Photoshop CS6, you can now run the Adobe setup. Either right click **Setup.exe**, or from the terminal:

```
cd /home/user/path/to/installer    
wine Set-up.exe
```

If everything worked as intended, you are now done. Photoshop should install like any other program via wine. It should even automatically appear in your programs list!

To answer your question on downloading Photoshop: Just get any Photoshop version compatible with the Windows operating system, and it will work in Ubuntu through wine. There is no Photoshop for Ubuntu, so this is the best option.
If you don't want to go through this seemingly hectic process to get Photoshop to run in Ubuntu, you can use an alternative photo editing tool that has the same (even more) capabilities than Adobe Photoshop. Its called `gimp`. Install it by"

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gimp
```

After the commands finish running, you will have Gimp amongst your applications in your launcher.